# Python: Saving a file before loading it(Windows 7)

Tags: python, windows, excel, file

Basically, I am looking for a way to tell my program to save a file before opening it. Say the situation is that I have a text file that is constantly being written on manually, yet my program is also constantly reading it. How do I tell my program to save the file BEFORE opening it every time?

I'm not 100% sure I am making much sense, if any clarification is required I'd be happy to provide it.

**Edit:** I am using excel files, basically I am going to be getting constant user data into excel from users logging in to meetings with their IDs.

Below is my while loop where I constantly open my workbook(excel file) and then update it if it changed. Later I write to an output file where I keep track of my users logging in to meetings.

```
 try:
     while True:
            book2= open_workbook('IDS.xlsx')
            sheet2=book2.sheet_by_index(0)
            IDs2=UpdatePoints(value,IDs2)
            writeBook.save("Counted.xls")
            time.sleep(0.5)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
     print 'interrupted!'
```

I would like to be able so save "book2" before I open it if it makes any sense.

Comment: You need to clarify what you are asking for.  Is your program doing the writing as well as reading, or is it another process?

Comment: I'm afraid you're right that the question doesn't make much sense. Can you clarify who is writing to the file and who is reading? Is it the same process doing both? If its two separate processes, do you control both of them?

Comment: I don't know too much about Excel programming, but I suspect you'd need to aproach this from the other end to do what you want. Can you change how the data is added to the excel files, so that it saves the file after each addition? I don't think there will be any easy way to do that from the Python side, at least, not from just touching the data file. And on another note, you may want to add the `excel` tag to the question.

Comment: So you mean you want to force the Excel process to save?  Is it running on the same host?  You could probably do this via DDE.  I would question whether there's a better way to solve the problem than this though.

Comment: You guys are right, I was approaching the problem from the wrong side. I will try to find a way to get my excel file to save automatically after each change. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is open by another process, you cannot tell that process to save it's changes before your program opens the file.  Your process can only read the changes that the other process has chosen to write.

What it sounds like you are describing is that there is a file that is open in one process that is making changes to the file -- say a text file that the user is editing in a text editor.  At the same time you want your process to open the file that is being changed and be able to read the pending changes to the file.  Thus, you want the other process to "save" or write out it's changes before your process opens the file.  That way your process will see the changes that have been made to the file.  So you want your process to "save" the file before it "reads" the file.

Unfortunately, this is not how programs and files interact.  Your process will only be able to see the changes when the other process decides to write the changes to the file.

Comment: I just realized how not very intelligent my question was. You absolutely got the idea and managed to succinctly explain why my reasoning was illogical. So thank you! I'll find another way to save automatically while writing.

Comment: All you need is for the user to save the changes before your program gets the updates.  I'm sure there is a way that your program can be notified by Windows when the watched file is written to.  I don't know how to do that in Python, but perhaps you can find something in another SO question.